# How to populate second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown using jsp and javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, dropdown

help me how to fetch second drop-down list based on selection of first.
In first drop-down I am fetching city from database, I want  to retrieve area names in second drop-down from database based on selection of city in first drop-down list. I am fetching data using my-sql database.
 i used this code to populate first dropdown from database...

```
 <select id = "city" style="padding: 10px; width:100%; border:1px solid #000;" name="rut">
        <%! int route;%>
        <%

        String sql = "select * from route";

        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
        route = Integer.parseInt( rs.getString(1));
    %>
        <option value = "<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>
    <%
     }

    %> 
</select>
```

now  i want to populate this dropdown with city area which is stored in database in same table where city is stored....

```
<select id="customers" name = "cust" style="padding: 10px; width:100%; border:1px solid #000;" >

            <%
                ResultSet rs1;
             String sql1 ="select * from customer where cust_route='"+route+"'"; 
             rs1 = st.executeQuery(sql1);
               while(rs1.next())
                {
                    out.println(rs1.toString());
            %>
            <option value="<%=rs1.getString(1)%>"><%=rs1.getString(2)%></option>

            <%}
            %>
        </select>
```

Comment: search for `jquery selection change`

Comment: what did you tried so far !!

Comment: i m not familiar with jquery.... @ScaryWombat
can u guide me with jsp and javascript

Comment: i m not getting idea how to do it so havent tried anything looking forward to use lost focus and getfocus event on dropdown to work with it.... @PacMan